# How to do I create a cgi-bin directory?

Tags: html, web, cgi, directory

I need a cgi-bin but I can't find one when I am connected on Filezilla or cPanel, it's just public_html and that's it.

What do I do? I have looked online and it says that I need to use a command line but I have no clue how I would do that!

Answer (score 0):

The "cgi-bin" directory does not exist until you create it with your FTP program at the top level of your Web site directory. From the perspective of your FTP program, it's just a normal directory (folder) that you can create, but it's treated differently by the server because of its special name.

Open your Filezilla program and connect to your website.
When you are in your top-level directory, (Where you see "public_html")
Right-click anywhere in the the window and select "create directory."
Simply name the directory "cgi-bin"
You're done!